# How can I connect to a remote tunnel on start-up (using VS Code for Desktop)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have VS Code for Desktop on my laptop, and VS Code for Desktop on my remote server as well. Both have the Remote Tunnels extension, and manually connecting works just fine.

However, I would like for VS Code to automatically connect to this tunnel when I start it up. Is there a way to make like a default workspace or something that automatically connects to a specified (or last-used) Remote Tunnel?

Thanks for any help!

Edit: I would also like for it to remember the folder that needs to be opened on the Remote Tunnel. This works when accessing the tunnel via webbrowser (because the folder is embedded in the URL) but doesn't work with VS Code for Desktop afaik...